# Having an issue connecting my LiveServer to Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, liveserver

Whenever I do a right click to open live-server, a pop up appears saying

'Windows cannot find 'google-chrome'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px1xO.png)

My Visual-Studio Code is installed, I have the Live-Server extensions, and it says that the  server port has started. Not sure what the issue is, would appreciate some help. My live-server used to go in Microsoft Edge, but I have to change its location for class, and I have had some trouble trying to get it back to Chrome. Formally started coding 4 weeks prior so I've never encountered something like this yet. Would appreciate the assistance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fahde.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change `liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser` to `chrome` rather than `google-chrome`.